# custom tslint rule to catch "=== undefined" not working

Tags: typescript, tslint

I've copied [this tslint rule](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/pull/1060/files#r58076945) into my project and got it working so now tslint picks up any `=== null` and makes it an error.

I now want to do the same thing but for the `undefined`. I have implemented it the same as the `null` one but changed the check to look for `ts.SyntaxKind.UndefinedKeyWord` instead of `ts.SyntaxKind.NullKeyword` and it for some reason doesn't pick up on `=== undefined`.

Why not if it is the same as the `null` one which is working?

noTripleEqualsNullRule.ts

```
import * as ts from "typescript";
import * as Lint from "tslint";

const OPTION_NO_NULL_KEYWORD = "no-null-keyword";

export class Rule extends Lint.Rules.AbstractRule {
    public static EQ_FAILURE_STRING = "Did you mean == null instead?";
    public static NEQ_FAILURE_STRING = "Did you mean != null instead?";

    public apply(sourceFile: ts.SourceFile): Lint.RuleFailure[] {
        const noTripleEqualsNullWalker = new NoTripleEqualsNullWalker(sourceFile, this.getOptions());
        return this.applyWithWalker(noTripleEqualsNullWalker);
    }
}

class NoTripleEqualsNullWalker extends Lint.RuleWalker {
    public visitBinaryExpression(node: ts.BinaryExpression) {
        if (this.isExpressionAllowed(node)) {
            const position = node.getChildAt(1).getStart();
            const expressionWidth = node.right.getFullWidth() + 3;
            this.handleBinaryComparison(position, expressionWidth, node.operatorToken.kind, node.right.kind);
        }

        super.visitBinaryExpression(node);
    }

    private handleBinaryComparison(position: number, expressionWidth: number, operator: ts.SyntaxKind, right: ts.SyntaxKind) {
        switch (operator) {
            case ts.SyntaxKind.EqualsEqualsEqualsToken:
                if (right === ts.SyntaxKind.NullKeyword) {
                    this.addFailure(this.createFailure(position, expressionWidth, Rule.EQ_FAILURE_STRING));
                }
                break;
            case ts.SyntaxKind.ExclamationEqualsEqualsToken:
                if (right === ts.SyntaxKind.NullKeyword) {
                    this.addFailure(this.createFailure(position, expressionWidth, Rule.NEQ_FAILURE_STRING));
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private isExpressionAllowed(node: ts.BinaryExpression) {
        const nullKeyword = ts.SyntaxKind.NullKeyword;

        return !this.hasOption(OPTION_NO_NULL_KEYWORD)
            && (node.left.kind ===  nullKeyword || node.right.kind === nullKeyword);
    }
}
```

noTripleEqualsUndefinedRule.ts

```
import * as ts from "typescript";
import * as Lint from "tslint";

const OPTION_NO_NULL_KEYWORD = "no-null-keyword";

export class Rule extends Lint.Rules.AbstractRule {
    public static EQ_FAILURE_STRING = "Did you mean == null instead?";
    public static NEQ_FAILURE_STRING = "Did you mean != null instead?";

    public apply(sourceFile: ts.SourceFile): Lint.RuleFailure[] {
        const noTripleEqualsNullWalker = new NoTripleEqualsNullWalker(sourceFile, this.getOptions());
        return this.applyWithWalker(noTripleEqualsNullWalker);
    }
}

class NoTripleEqualsNullWalker extends Lint.RuleWalker {
    public visitBinaryExpression(node: ts.BinaryExpression) {
        if (this.isExpressionAllowed(node)) {
            const position = node.getChildAt(1).getStart();
            const expressionWidth = node.right.getFullWidth() + 3;
            this.handleBinaryComparison(position, expressionWidth, node.operatorToken.kind, node.right.kind);
        }

        super.visitBinaryExpression(node);
    }

    private handleBinaryComparison(position: number, expressionWidth: number, operator: ts.SyntaxKind, right: ts.SyntaxKind) {
        switch (operator) {
            case ts.SyntaxKind.EqualsEqualsEqualsToken:
                if (right === ts.SyntaxKind.UndefinedKeyword) {
                    this.addFailure(this.createFailure(position, expressionWidth, Rule.EQ_FAILURE_STRING));
                }
                break;
            case ts.SyntaxKind.ExclamationEqualsEqualsToken:
                if (right === ts.SyntaxKind.UndefinedKeyword) {
                    this.addFailure(this.createFailure(position, expressionWidth, Rule.NEQ_FAILURE_STRING));
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private isExpressionAllowed(node: ts.BinaryExpression) {
        const nullKeyword = ts.SyntaxKind.UndefinedKeyword;

        return !this.hasOption(OPTION_NO_NULL_KEYWORD)
            && (node.left.kind ===  nullKeyword || node.right.kind === nullKeyword);
    }
}
```

Comment: undefined is not the same as null please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined

Comment: @jshamble I know undefined is not the same as null. That's why I created a new tslint rule for undefined, not null.

Answer (score 1):

The linter thinks that the kind of `undefined` is `SyntaxKind.Identifier` rather than `SyntaxKind.UndefinedKeyword`. This *kind of* makes sense, since undefined can be redefined – but is still unfortunate.

If you're sure that undefined has not been redefined anywhere in your codebase, you could check `node.getText() === "undefined"` instead.